# Fill a block of the maximum of data

Tags: algorithm

I want to select the data to fill a block in order the have the minimum remaining space:

e.g:

```
size of Data1  = 16 bytes
size of Data2 = 125 bytes
size of Data3 = 4 bytes
size of Data4 = 4 bytes
size of block  = 140 bytes
```

So here we can put Data2, Data3 and Data4 in the block.

Do you know any generic algorithm?

Comment: This is indeed a 0/1 knapsack problem. I am able to solve it. See [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo) and you will be able to as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the discrete knapsack problem (and it is NP-complete if I remember well). Some googling will certainly lead you to an implementation!

Comment: Or Bin Packing, if all of the data has to be assigned somewhere.

Comment: For example, here is a [C++ implementation](http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-solve-knapsack-problem-using-dynamic-programming/).